# TS react Jest SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am new to react TS jest. I am getting the below error when I try to run a simple test.
I'm not using Babel in the repo Tried a lot of things but of no use.
I can test normal assertion, but when I use a component, I get an error.
Tried with ReactDom.render as well still the same error.

[image: Unexpected token error]

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: "reports/coverage",
  coverageReporters: ["json", "json-summary", "text", "lcov"],
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "json", "jsx", "node", "ts", "tsx"],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts"],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
  }
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules", "**/__mocks__/**/*", "**/__tests__/*.*", "jest.config.js", "**/*.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext", // adds support for ESNext functionality
      "DOM" // adds support for 'window' other dom methods
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,

    /* JSX support */
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "declaration": true,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    // "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    /* Advanced Options */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

jest.setup.ts

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./src/index.tsx",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "version": "0.4.0",
  "contributors": [],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest -c ./jest.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "29.1.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.27.1",
    "jest": "29.1.0",
    "jest-config": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-emotion": "^10.0.32",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
  }
}
```

Counter.tsx

```
import React from "react";

export const Counter: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button >Add One</button>
      <div role="contentinfo">Count is 0</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Counter.test.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Counter } from "../Counter";

describe('counter', () => {
  it('handle click', () => {
    render(<Counter />);

    const divElement = screen.getByRole("contentinfo");
    expect(divElement).toHaveTextContent("Count is 0");
  })
})
```